# Prove there's a$\ θ$ such that $\ \frac{2}{π}=\cos(\frac{θπ}{2})+\sin(\frac{π}{2})(1-θ)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove there's a$\ θ$ such that $\ \frac{2}{π}=\cos(\frac{θπ}{2})+\sin(\frac{π}{2})(1-θ)$ **using the mean value theorem.**

I really have no clue on how to aproach this problem, even trying to solve this without using the MVT seems hard.

The MTV I was thought yields as a results that $\ f(P)-f(Q)=\nabla f(Q_0)(P-Q)$ with$\ Q_0$ in the segment that joins$\ P$ and$\ Q$.

Need some sugestions on how to even try to approach this, thanks!

Comment: Probably you mean $\sin (\theta\pi/2)$,rather than $\sin (\pi/2)$ above.

Comment: ... or perhaps $\sin\left(\frac{(1-\theta)\pi}{2}\right)$?

Comment: That is actually how it is written in my assignment, why does the way it's written causes so much problem to you, guys?

Comment: Because $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$, so it would be slightly redundant.

Comment: Maybe you mean "using the intermediate value theorem"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see immediately how to use the mean value theorem... But, I think it is sufficient to notice that, defining
\begin{equation}
f(\theta) = \cos(\theta \pi / 2) + \sin(\pi / 2)(1−\theta) - 2/ \pi,
\end{equation}
we have $f(0)=2-2/ \pi > 0$ and $f(1)=-2/ \pi < 0$.
Being $f(\theta)$ continuous, this implies that there exists a $\bar \theta \in (0,1)$ such that $f(\bar \theta) = 0$.

Comment: Seems like Michaels' solution which came in slightly before yours.

Comment: I should have typed faster! :)

Comment: Tobia-- I've done the same many times, no criticism intended, and +1.

Comment: I was here when you guys typed your answers, yours was literally like 2 or 3 seconds apart from Michael's, thank you both

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(\theta)=\cos\frac{\pi\theta}{2}+\sin\frac{\pi(1-\theta)}{2}-\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Hence, $f(0)=2-\frac{2}{\pi}>0$ and $f(1)=-\frac{2}{\pi}<0$ and since $f$ is a continuous function, we are done.

Comment: This uses the intermediate value theorem, rather than the mean value theorem. But it works, and is the straightforward way to do the problem. +1.